# Unable to resolve "clr", Iron Python application in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, ironpython

I am trying to use Visual Studio to develop IronPython applications. The main reason for choosing this IDE is to use IntelliSense to speed up the development.

In Visual Studio I have added Python Development and I have created a new IronPython Application. I have checked the Python Environments and they seem to be correct and up to date.

But when I type:

```
import clr
```

I get "Unable to resolve "clr". IntelliSense may be missing from this module". And indeed, IntelliSense does not work.

However, if I open a Python Interactive Windows and do the exact same process I get a working IntelliSense inside the console.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your enviroment options. Go to:

```
Tools > Options > Python Tools > Enviroment Options
```

And change the default enviroment to IronPython.